# go-swagger WriteResponse

Tags: http, go, go-swagger

I am using go-swagger but I have an case where I want to write a string to a response.   I need to call the "WriteResponse" function

```
WriteResponse(rw http.ResponseWriter, producer runtime.Producer)
```

The issue that I am having is that I don't know how to convert a string to a http.ResponseWriter and create a runtime.Producer.

If it helps here is a snippit of my code...

```
//convert the database response to a string array of valid JSON
stringArray, conversionError := plan.ConvertPlanArrayToString(response)
if conversionError != nil {
    return swaggerPlan.NewPlanGetTemplatePlanInternalServerError()
}

//Need to convert string value
stringValue := stringArray[0]
return swaggerPlan.NewPlanGetTemplatePlanOK().WriteResponse(NOT SURE HOW TO CREATE http.ResponseWriter, runtime.Producer)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You don't convert a string to a ResponseWriter. But you can _write_ a string to a ResponseWriter.  As for your runtime.Producer type--what is that? It's not part of the standard library runtime package.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Flimzy, you'll have to write your string to the `http.ResponseWriter`, which is probably what your `WriteResponse` function does anyway.

The code you provided should somewhere be called from within a handler function:

```
func (...) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  // your code should be here and you can pass the http.ResponseWriter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both very much, you were very helpful.  It worked exactly like you said but in go-swagger it is slightly different.

My handler was updated to return a custom "ResponderFunc" and then I could write my output directly to it.   Worked great, here is my code...

```
//Handle a 200 by sending the list of plans back as json
    return middleware.ResponderFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, pr runtime.Producer) {
        rw.WriteHeader(200)
        rw.Write(byteArrayPlan)
    })
```